# Why thread Id changes in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using Thread to store Locale and pass it down the layers.

In my middleware I set the selected locale in the current thread as follow:

```
Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot('SelectedLocale'), selectedLocale /* I get this value form the request */);
```

Then in the rest of my code, I use this line to access that data:

```
var selectedLocale = Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot('SelectedLocale'));
```

However, this sometimes works, and sometimes returns null.

I used `var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` and realized that **Id** changes sometimes.

Why is it so? How can I make sure that I'm using the same thread during my request processing?

**Update**

I'm using the same technique for my APIs and for my Razor Page applications.

My APIs work just fine. They never fail.

However, my Razor Page applications fail almost 70% of the time. But they also work sometimes.

I think there must be something related to the Razor Pages here.

Comment: Are you performing `async` operations anywhere in the code, which may be returning control to a different thread?  Taking a step back... What is the driving reason behind *why* you want all of the code to always run on the same thread and not let the underlying system manage that for you?

Comment: @David, I'm not using async/await in my code. The only exception is the middleware that reads the selected locale. The reason that I need this, is to share the selected locale in the entire C# code instead of passing it down. Just like React's Context instead of passing props.

Comment: I don't think you should be using Threads for this kind of information. May be it should be part of the user's session state. If it's relevant then it should really be passed between the layers of your application using model/DTO classes.

Comment: @phuzi, makes no difference. User session is a web-tier concept. I want to access data in my business and data access classes. This means that I should know about use session in my data access.

Comment: If it's needed in each layer then it should be passed between each layer without being magically available in something that's not guaranteed to be persistant. Create an object that captures the relevant info and pass it down through the layers. It will be easier for someone new to the code base to follow too and therefore easier to maintain. You're already experiencing issues where stuff is being run on different threads - don't use thread's CultureInfo!

Answer (score 4):

> I'm using Thread to store Locale and pass it down the layers.
>
> I'm not using async/await in my code

If you're still thinking in threads and not using async/await, you're doing it wrong. Threads are too low-level of a construct to be using in application code, especially web application code.

It's all tasks and contexts now. If you use Razor pages, stuff *will* be handled async by the framework. Just use the HttpContext to pass entities from one middleware to the next.

Though the HttpContext has its own problems.

More reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0.

Comment: either layered architecture, or onion architecture, I can't pass HttpContext to lower code classes. You tell me that I should use HttpContext in my data access layer?

Comment: Definitely not, but you also shouldn't be relying on thread properties within your DAL in an application whose plumbing definitely uses async/await. At some point you'll be passing a mere string to your queries. Pull that up to become a parameter.

Comment: that's the entire point here. Parameter drilling becomes a nasty thing very soon. That's why React has created Context API. Imaging adding a dumb `string selectedLocale` to over a thousand methods. That's extremely inefficient.

Comment: Why would you need to add it to a thousand methods. Create an object to handle these parameters once you get passed more than a couple then you can just pass the object rather than the individual variables and access it only when you need to. This object then becomes your context. And it also allows you to trivially unit test these methods.

Comment: I wouldn't take React as a shining beacon of a well-designed application framework, but that's perhaps personal. If locale is such an integral part of your code, surely you'll have some kind of architecture denoting a common query, just like pagination? Chuck it into that. You're basically asking for global variables, and there's many ways to do that wrong. Perhaps you're helped by `AsyncLocal<T>`. Perhaps if you'd show more context (ha-ha) in your question, more to-the-point answers can be given.