# How can I access the selected locale in non-UI code in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement a central querying place that adds the selected locale to **ALL** queries going to the database.

I know I can use `HttpContext` or session to store and retrieve the user's currently selected locale.

But aside from adding `string selectedLocale` to hundreds of methods (parameter drilling), how can I access the currently selected locale in my data access for example? Or in my business?

How can I have something similar to React's Context API for C#?

Right now, I'm using `Thread.SetData` and `Thread.GetData`, but it [has bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73650385/why-thread-id-changes-in-asp-net-core/73650624#73650624).

Comment: You need to pass a parameter from client to server in the HTTP message or in the body of the message.  Parameters can be either in the URL after the question mark or an HTTP header.  If security issues, than you should not put into URL which is not encrypted.

Comment: @jdweng, I'm not talking about passing parameters between clients and the server. I'm talking about sharing a parameter in my server-side code files.

Comment: How are you going to get local from client in the client-server connection?  Or do you want to use the Server local?

Comment: @jdweng, you get the selected locale from the HTTP request. From anywhere. URL, headers, cookie, anywhere. Now you have it. You want to share it across your server-side files. Either you pass it as parameter everywhere, or you simply make a context to access it there.

Comment: Yes.  You need to add column to database and then update the mapping to c# classes as well as taking from request and putting into context.

Comment: Hi @AliEXE, If you use HttpContext ot session to store the selected locale, no need adding `string selectedLocale` to hundreds of methods. You can access the HttpContext or Session every where unless you inject the service. What are your stuck in?

Comment: @Rena, that's our last choice. And it seems that we have do to do it. The point is, we make all of our layers dependent upon `HttpContext`.