# How can I access HttpContext in my data access code in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Based on my previous two questions [Why thread Id changes in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73650385/why-thread-id-changes-in-asp-net-core) and [How can I access the selected locale in non-UI code in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73650797/how-can-i-access-the-selected-locale-in-non-ui-code-in-asp-net-core), we decided that we want to use `HttpContext` in our data access code.

Our data access project is a different project. Thus we added this to `DataAccess.csproj`:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Then in our `Startup.cs` we registered `IHttpContextAccessor`:

```
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Now in my `CustomerRepository.cs` for example, I want to get an instance of the `HttpContext` class, so that I can access its `Items` property.

I don't want **constructor injection** because that makes a lot of problem for our architecture and causes a huge change that we can't do now. I also don't want to pass it down as a parameter.

How can I get it?

Comment: You shouldn't. The Data project does not have to know anything about HttpContext. Why don't you pass the `Items` to the `CustomerRepository` as a simple method parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you're needing to access HTTP concerns in the inner layers, you should abstract it, you cant't access it in the data access layer directly.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped<IYourHttpUserAccessor, YourHttpUserAccessor>();
```

then implement YourHttpUserAccessor with this code:

```
Public class YourHttpAccessor : IYourHttpAccessor {
    IHttpContextAccessor _httpAccessor;

    public YourHttpAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor) {
        _httpAccessor = httpAccessor;
    }

    public IDictionary HttpContextItems => _httpAccessor.HttpContext?.Items;
}
```

Comment: He said he cannot use constructor injection, so this answer does not help him.